# I think something is probably true, but I don’t have all the evidence to prove it

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for word to use to the following situation, I want to indicate a weak belief. I think something is probably true, but I don’t have all the evidence to prove it.

I am trying to express the following in a more succinct manner.

> ***Without having reviewed all cases in detail, this case which I have reviewed in detail*** would seem to be an extreme example.

I did consider *notationally*, but that doesn’t seem a valid usage.

> ***Notationally*** this would seem to be an extreme example.

Comment: so 'at first glance' this sounds extreme?

Comment: You probably mean ***notionally***

Comment: @marcellothearcane Had the same idea, but that suggests a very short time span which isn't true of this case

Comment: @Jim that is indeed the word I was looking for.

Comment: If your intent is to have the audience reading ~understand~ that you have reviewed the cases ~in detail~ I think it might be misguided to try to be succinct by using a word not very commonly used or understood(or subject to varying degrees of interpretation). "reviewed in detail' seems worthy of being clearly stated and stressed to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jim suggested, I was indeed looking for [notionally](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/notionally);

> pertaining to or expressing a notion or idea
>
> abstract, theoretical, or speculative, as reflective thought.